# Uploading Image to the web service - Beginner

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, asihttprequest

I have to upload an image taken via the camera or uploaded via `uiimagepickerview`. I am using ASIHTTPRequest.

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" forKey:@"photo"];
```

1.) Since i am taking the photo from the iPhone camera or uploading it from the `uiimagepickerview`, i need to know what value should i set for `setFile` (replacement text for `@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg"`) ?

2.) I also need to test this application, so does anyone know the corresponding PHP code where i could display the image taken (on the web browser). Tutorials or sample codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get answer on the 1st question, please, take a look on the following code fragment:

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    BOOL isImage = ([[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] isEqualToString:kUTTypeImage]);
    if (isImage) {
        self.request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
        UIImage *originalImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(originalImage, 0.7);
        [self.request setData:imageData
                 withFileName:@"photo.jpg"
               andContentType:@"image/jpeg"
                       forKey:@"photo"];
        [self.request start];
    }
}
```

Please consider to add property into your UIImagePiclerController delegate class

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) ASIFormDataRequest *request;
```

It will allow you to stop request or at least set it's delegate to nil, if your object is deallocated, by simply implementing

```
- (void) dealloc {
    [self.request cancel];
    self.request.delegate = nil;
    [request release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What is `0.7`in `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(originalImage, 0.7)` ? I am using ARC in my code. Do you know the corresponding PHP code, where i could test if this is working ?

Comment: No problem. You may check the 0.7 is JPEG compression quality. This argument values range is [0.0;1.0]. According to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW9), "The value 0.0 represents the maximum compression (or lowest quality) while the value 1.0 represents the least compression (or best quality)." You understand that to use PHP you'll have to setup web server with PHP module etc. I think it's better check using some images hosting with its own API.

Comment: Why did you add `#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>` ? Which method uses it ?

Comment: It is required for kUTTypeImage.

Answer (score 0):

You should Add Image to the Request Body as image data.

[Take a Look of ASIHttp Framework](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

[And Even you don't get Please Go through this Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ImageClient/Introduction/Intro.html)