# Get an image from photo library and upload it to web service by name and path

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage

I am creating a web service based iphone application in which a certain place i need to post an image on to the web for which i want to select image from photo gallery of phone and then i need to get the name and the path of the image on textfield and then uploading of the image.

or when pressing the browse button image picker will show all the image of the iphone and by selecting image it will return its path and name by which we can upload it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555101/uploading-image-to-the-web-service-beginner/9555900#9555900) first.

To fully understand the answer you should also need to read [UIImagePickerController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) and [ASIHTTPRequest documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

As ASIHTTPRequest library is not supported more by its author, you may use another open source solution - [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or even the Cocoa classes, described in the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165-BCICJDHA)

Comment: Thanks for reply... but i only want the name and path of image how to get from the selected image of photo gallery. And to upload it know how to do.

Comment: You won't get path to the image, only the UIImage class instance as a member of dictionary passed as an argument to your <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> protocol conforming class object, then you may save it in your app's folder if you wish so, and use that path and file name or simply construct NSData object as in the code snippet in similar question answer and use it directly to post to your web service.

Comment: I am not getting what you are saying

Comment: Sorry, I got you wrong. The URL to the image may be fetched from info dictionary with a help of `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` key.